# Microsoft Entity Framework - when to use it?

Tags: agile, mvc, entity-framework, waterfall

I am researching Microsoft entity framework and I am confused about when it should or should not be used. I am interested in the relationship between entity framework and product management methodologies, design methodologies and .net web development frameworks.

The information I am finding online isn't enough. Does anyone have any information on this or know where I would be able to find out more information?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is very broad and opinion based.  Also a close duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108855/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-orm-tools since EF is an ORM

Comment: wonder what could be the reason to think that this question would be a better fit here than [it was at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46941699/839601)

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not used it, what I understand is it is .Net's Object Relational Mapping (ORM).

"The Entity Framework enables developers to work with data in the form of domain-specific objects and properties, such as customers and customer addresses, without having to concern themselves with the underlying database tables and columns where this data is stored. With the Entity Framework, developers can work at a higher level of abstraction when they deal with data, and can create and maintain data-oriented applications with less code than in traditional applications." -- source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview

I picked the above few lines because that sums up why/when you would use it. When you want to uncouple your business logic & UI layers from the underlying data storage. Ideally, you should be able to change the underlying data storage from one database platform to another without having to modify bits throughout your code. You should be able to moved from a relational database platform to non-relational or a cloud based data service.

It is generally a bad idea to have all aspects of your app directly coupled to your database and dependent on the database platform, table structures, columns, etc.

Comment: Getting downvotes, and lacking comments I am thinking that is because people are opposed to using EF. I am not recommending that anyone use it, but simply providing a high-level use case for ORM.  If you are a .Net developer with no ORM framework employed, and you want to stick with MS provided components of your dev stack, EF would be a good ORM to consider.